# Saying Misod and Reshut (introduction) for piyutim, then skipping them

Tags: minhag, tefilla, song-poetry, high-holidays

I have seen that many yeshivos (and recently, even some shuls) often say just Misod and the Reshus on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur, and then skip the actual piyutim they are meant to introduce!
This is even more evident in Musaf where they say Misod and go directly to Zachreinu L'Chaim. But it's clear that Misod is there because we are introducing piyutim in the first brachos (as is the case with other yotzros on yom tov and daled parshios).  And therefore, on the second day of RH in Musaf, there is no Misod, even though we still say Unesaneh Tokef.

Question 1 - Does anyone know of any rationale for such a practice?  (I understand that the goal is to save time in order to say other parts of the davening more slowly, but saying the first three piyutim (the ones that follow Misod) does not really add more than 2-3 minutes, (and they add so much to the davening.)

Question 2 - If they really need to skip parts of the davening, why not say less stanzas in Melech Elyon, and not lose out on the beautiful piyutim that connect the brachos that we just had a whole long Reshus ("Yereisi biftzosi" on first day) to introduce them?

Question 3 - And if they specifically don't want to say these piyutim, why say Misod and the Reshus at all?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14450/759

Comment: Thanks. This is related but doesn't answer the question here. We are talking about longer piyutim that require Misod (unlike in Mussaf of Shkalim/Hachodesh), but the Misod cannot (from what I understand) be referring just to Melech Elyon/Hashem Melech which is what many yeshivos say, since the piyut always immediately follows Misod. Otherwise, why do we interrupt the chazarah with Misod at this point if not to add in these very "lofty" piyutim?

Comment: Also, the Reshus is clearly a later introduction (see Saks Machzor for example) to the earlier piyut of Hakalir. How can they let go of this much earlier piyut, and just interrupt the davening with a later introduction to the piyut they are skipping, completely out of context?

Comment: +1, nice question, but, if I understand it correctly, your question #1 is simply asking why some synagogues omit some _yotz'ros_ and the like, which is a very general question somewhat unrelated to the very specific one (or two) you're otherwise asking and should probably be asked as a separate question rather than lumped together with the rest here.

Comment: According to Rabbi Artscroll, "Misod..." is an introduction to *all* piyutim contained in the Shmoneh Esreh, saying "We wouldn't do this ourselves, but others told us to do this, so we'll alter the nusach of the tefilah with these piyutim." If so, even one piyut would make it acceptable

Comment: msh210 - Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was asking in #1 specifically about the rationale of saying Misod and the Reshus that follows and then skipping the piyutim that they introduce, being that it seems very inconsistent. The question about yotzros in general, as you said, is a separate question. This is a question about saying an introduction and then skipping the piyut. Same question would apply to those who say "ohr olam" in bircos shma (also an introduction to the yotzros, as can be seen in the machzor on other yamim tovim), and then skipping the actual yotzros.

Comment: b a - I agree that Misod is an introduction to the series of piyutim said, but it is clear that it particularly relates to the piyutim that follow immediately. Otherwise, why don't we say Misod on the second day of RH, when these piyutim between the brachos are not said but we still have many other piyutim later on including Unesane Tokef, Chol Maaminim etc..?        Further, it makes no sense to say Misod in Musaf without any piyut that follows immediately and just go to Zachreinu. When we introduce the idea of piyut, it's because we're about to say one!

Comment: b a- Also, the Reshus said in Shachris is clearly an introduction to the piyut that follows: "At Chil Yom Pekuda". These piyutim of Hakalir on first day of RH (who lived in Eretz Yisrael) were seen in such high regards that a poetic introduction was composed hundreds of years later in Europe. Who are we to neglect them, and then scream out with so much Kavanah this later "introduction" to them completely out of context (just because some printer of the machzor once put in a note that the Aron is open from the Reshus and closed for the actual piyutim)?

Comment: @aaron, the note about "Or Olam" might be slightly different, according to my custom, emendations to tefillah such as "Or Olam" or the short "Emet V'yatziv" should still be said without the piyutim, whereas Misod should not be recited without the piyut.

Comment: Re Q 2 - "Melech Elyon" has already been abbreviated. It used to alternate with a verse that started "Melech Evyon". A leftover piece of that still remains near the end of that piyut. I think both Art Scroll & Birnnbaum explain this, further.