# Please explain the "introductory" paragraph for High Holiday Piyutim

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, high-holidays, chazarat-hashatz

Near the beginning of the reader's repetition of the High Holiday Amidah, there is an introductory paragraph (Nusach Ashkenaz and I assume in Nusach Sefarad, as well) that starts:

> מסוד חכמים ונבונים ומלמד דעת מבינים

My translation:

> From the secrets (consultation?) of the sages and the discerning ones
>   and from the teachings of the knowledge of the experts

I am seeking some nuances in the above phrasing. (Feel free to correct the above translation, especially if I am way off, somewhere.) Specifically,

- סוד means "secret". Is there any nuance of secrets that may be implied, here? If so, what types of secrets?
- Why is the term סוד attached to חכמים ונבונים ? Is there any difference between these 2 classes of people that they are described differently, or are these just synonyms, i.e. are חכמים also נבונים?
- Are the מבינים a 3rd group different from the previous two? Why is למד ascribed to them and not the others?

Comment: I dont know if im understanding your question correctly, but the reason for that small paragraph is that in truth it is forbidden to interrupt the repetition of Shemoneh Esrei for anything. We say that sort of as a disclaimer that we are only following the instructions of the sages who instructed us to add piyutim. That also is the definition of "secrets". We dont know exactly why they instituted it and HOW (meaning against halacha), but we trust their secrets

Comment: and from the learning wisdom of understanding people

Comment: @Mennyg What you have appears to be a partial answer. It would be better of you could back it up with some source, but, I'm fine with your explanation.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19106/saying-misod-and-reshut-introduction-for-piyutim-then-skipping-them

Comment: בסוד ישרים ועדה