# Why don't we say "Misod" for Geshem and Tal?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, weather, musaf, geshem-tal-ruach

On Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur, the Shat"z says a short paragraph at the beginning of his repetition that starts with the words "מסוד חכמים ונבונים," which is an explanation for the insertion of extra *piyutim* in the middle of חזרת הש"ץ.

**Why don't we have the Shat"z say מסוד for תפילת גשם and תפילת טל?**
(*Or if we do, why isn't it printed in the siddurim?*)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14420/759

Comment: Just to note: Not all places say either _Tefilat Tal_ or _Tefilat Geshem_ as part of _Chazarat ha-Shatz_ , but rather on its own before [the _Chatzi Qadish_ before] the silent _Musaf_.

Comment: @TamirEvan I didn't know that....I've only ever heard Tal/Geshem in an Askenazi shul. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Shokhet @TamirEvan's comment is even for _Ashk'nazi_ synagogues. Just fyi.

Comment: We don't say it for the Kerovos on Purim either - nor for many [all?] of the 4 special weeks before Nissan.

Comment: @msh210 I didn't know that either....learn new things every day!

Comment: @DannySchoemann, in my book of yotzros and kerovos for Minhog Frankfurt a/M schuls, it includes מסוד for ד׳ פרשיות

Comment: @noach only for Shacharit though where there is a Kedushta. The Shivata in Musaf never gets a Reshut.

Answer (score 6):

The קרובות for Musaph of Shemini Atzeres is known as a שבעתא and, although many consider the main part to זכור אב (in מנהג פולין) or איום זכור נא (in מנהג אשכנז), the main part was once אף-ברי. This פיוט, written by רבי אלעזר הקליר, was originally split into seven parts (hence, why it is known as a **שבע**תא). Each part was for a different ברכה in חזרת הש''ץ. The nature of a שבעתא is that each part of the פיוט is recited just before the חתימה of the ברכה (i.e. immediately before ברוך אתה השם...)

I do not know a source for the following. **One is allowed מעיקר הדין to make you own תפלות before the חתימה of each ברכה in the עמידה. We see this in most סידורים with the ברכה of רפואה. Therefore, my theory is that when you have a שבעתא, where the פיוט is inserted just before the חתימה, it is like adding your own תפלות (even though it's in חזרת הש''ץ) and so מסוד חכמים ונבונים is not necessary.**

The same can be said for the קרובות for Musaph of the first day of Pesach, which also was originally a שבעתא. We can apply this to the קרובות of Musaph for שבת שקלים and שבת החודש and originally for other days as well, like שבת זכור and שבת פרה.

The full שבעתא for Shemini Atzeres and First Day Pesach can be found in the Goldschmidt Koren Machzorim, the first of which can be viewed [here](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Goldschmidt_Machzor_Succos.pdf). The שבעתא of שבת זכור and of שבת פרה are found in מחזור שבחי ישורון.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Also what is a קרובות

Comment: @robev I have edited to make the answer more clear.

Comment: @robev Also, קרובות is פיוטים in חזרת הש''ץ.

Comment: An interesting parallel to you argument could be the מערבית

Comment: @robev קרובות is another spelling for קרובץ (the piyutim for Purim)